# Maximizing a set of finite functions which disagree for at least two values

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I wish to find the maximum possible cardinality of the following set of functions:

$\{c_i :[r] \rightarrow [n] : \forall i \neq j, \exists x \neq y,$ with $  c_i(x) \neq c_j(x)$ and $c_i(y) \neq c_j(y) \}$

In other words, how large can I make a set of functions from $[r] \rightarrow [n]$ such that each pair of these functions disagree for at least 2 inputs

Comment: Depends on $[r]$ and $[n]$. What are they?

Comment: i would like a general formula for any r and n if possible